# Who are Rogue and Sting and when were they first revealed?

Tags: fairy-tail

My friend is really into *Fairy Tail* and I watched a really good fight from it with Rogue and Sting vs Natsu and Gajeel. But he said that he didn't know who Rogue and Sting were. So I was wondering who they are and when they first showed up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rogue and Sting are members of the Sabertooth guild. They make their debut at the start of the Grand Magic Games arc, in anime episode 151 (Title: Sabertooth) and manga chapter 258 (Title: Sabertooth). Rogue is a Shadow Dragon Slayer, while Sting is a Light Dragon Slayer.

[image: Rogue and Sting]